# Impossible variableListener corruption with custom variableListener

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to optimize a Scheduling problem for my University.

To optimize the compactness of my Lessons I am trying to update a List of all Lessons on the same day in my Lesson class, which is the planning entity.
I do this via a planningVariableListener

This is my Lesson class:

```
private int id;
private Course course;
private Period period;
private Room room;
private int blockLength = 1;

private boolean prime = false;
private boolean uKW = false;
private boolean gKW = false;
private boolean FWPM = false;
private boolean biWeekly = false;
private boolean pinned = false;

private List<Student> fwpmStudents = new ArrayList<>();
private int altId = 0;
private String collisionReason;
private String group = "NO_GROUP";
public String[] groupArray;

private List<Lesson> sameDay = new ArrayList<>();

public Lesson() {

}

@PlanningPin
public boolean isPinned() {
    return pinned;
}

public void setPin(boolean pin) {
    pinned = pin;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Course getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(Course course) {
    this.course = course;
}

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "periodId")
public Period getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(Period period) {
    this.period = period;
}

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "roomId") //IDK if nullable is accepted
public Room getRoom() {
    return room;
}

public void setRoom(Room room) {
    this.room = room;
}

public boolean isPrime() {
    return prime;
}

public void setPrime(boolean prime) {
    this.prime = prime;
}

public int getBlockLength() {
    return blockLength;
}

public void setBlockLength(int blockLength) {
    this.blockLength = blockLength;
}

public boolean getUKWFlag() {
    return uKW;
}

public void setUKWFlag(boolean straight) {
    this.uKW = straight;
}

public boolean getGKWFlag() {
    return gKW;
}

public void setGKWFlag(boolean gKW) {
    this.gKW = gKW;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(String group) {
    this.group = group;
}

public int getAltId() {
    return altId;
}

public void setAltId(int altId) {
    this.altId = altId;
}

public boolean getFWPM() {
    return FWPM;
}

public void setFWPM(boolean FWPM) {
    this.FWPM = FWPM;
}

public boolean isBiWeekly() {
    return biWeekly;
}

public void setBiWeekly(boolean biWeekly) {
    this.biWeekly = biWeekly;
}

public String[] getGroupArray() {
    return groupArray;
}

public void setGroupArray(String[] groupArray) {
    this.groupArray = groupArray;
}

public void addFWPMStudent(Student student) {
    this.fwpmStudents.add(student);
}

public List<Student> getFWPMStudents() {
    return this.fwpmStudents;
}

public String getCollisionReason() {
    return collisionReason;
}

public void setCollisionReason(String collisionReason) {
    this.collisionReason = collisionReason;
}

public boolean collides(Lesson lesson) {
    return CollisionDetector.getCollision(this,lesson);
}

public boolean globalCollides(Lesson lesson) {
    return CollisionDetector.getGlobalCollision(this, lesson);
}

public boolean softCollides(Lesson lesson) {
    return CollisionDetector.softFWPMCollision(this, lesson);
}

public boolean prefCollides(Preference preference) {
    return CollisionDetector.getPreferenceCollision(this, preference);
}

public String toString() {
    return this.getId()
            + " " + this.getCourse().getSemester().getShortName()
            + " " + this.getCourse().getLecturer().getShortName()
            + " " + this.getCourse().getSubject().getShortName()
            + " " + this.getRoom().getNumber() + " " + this.getGroup()
            + "\t" + this.getPeriod().getDay() + " " + this.getPeriod().getHour() + " " + this.getBlockLength();
}

public void addSameDay(Lesson lesson) {
    this.sameDay.add(lesson);
}

public void removeSameDay(Lesson lesson) {
    this.sameDay.remove(lesson);
}

@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = DayLessonVariableListener.class,
        sources = {@PlanningVariableReference( variableName = "period")})
public List<Lesson> getSameDay() {
    return this.sameDay;
}

public void setSameDay(List<Lesson> sameDay) {
    this.sameDay = sameDay;
}

public boolean isOnlyLesson() {
    if (sameDay.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

This is my custom variableListener

```
private void update(ScoreDirector<ScheduleSolution> scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
    List<Lesson> lessons = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getLessons();
    for (Lesson l : lessons) {
        if (l.getPeriod().getDay() == lesson.getPeriod().getDay()){
            if (!l.equals(lesson)) {
                scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(lesson, "sameDay");
                lesson.addSameDay(l);
                scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(lesson, "sameDay");
            }
        }
    }
    Iterator<Lesson> iter = lesson.getSameDay().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Lesson x = iter.next();
        if (x.getPeriod().getDay() != lesson.getPeriod().getDay()) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(lesson, "sameDay");
            iter.remove();
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(lesson, "sameDay");
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
}

@Override
public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
}

@Override
public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
    update(scoreDirector, lesson);
}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
    update(scoreDirector, lesson);
}

@Override
public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {
}

@Override
public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Lesson lesson) {

}
```

If i run this, i get following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Impossible VariableListener corruption: the expectedWorkingScore (0hard/-50soft) is not the workingScore (0hard/0soft) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables after completedAction (137 AIF2 Koller üphy HS134 P3   4 2 2 {Day: 4 Hour: 2 -> Day: 4 Hour: 2}).
>   But all the shadow variable values are still the same, so this is impossible.
>   Maybe run with FULL_ASSERT if you aren't already, to fail earlier.
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:475)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(DefaultSolverScope.java:140)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractPhaseScope.java:171)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.predictWorkingStepScore(AbstractPhase.java:169)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.doStep(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:102)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:92)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
>       at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:173)
>       at app.Main.solve(Main.java:35)
>       at app.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Maybe i am overlooking something, but i dont know how to fix this.
For my Scheduling it is possible for two Lessons to be at the same time for some cases, due to the alternating nature of these two lessons.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** So i have resolved this error message, after working over my customVariableListener, there seemed to have been a consistency issue with the methods called in before and after of the scoreDirector.

Now what i wanted to do is call a softConstraint based on the shadow variables.
Is this not allowed? Is this some sort of concurrency issue?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: UndoMove corruption: the beforeMoveScore (0hard/-20soft) is not the undoScore (0hard/-10soft) which is the uncorruptedScore (0hard/-10soft) of the workingSolution.
>     1) Enable EnvironmentMode FULL_ASSERT (if you haven't already) to fail-faster in case there's a score corruption.
>     2) Check the Move.createUndoMove(...) method of the moveClass (class util.helpers.optaplanner.moves.ResistantSwapMove). The move (70 AIF2 Mareczek peme LS103 EM7/EM8 {Day:1 Hour:3} <-> 136 AIF2 Koller phys A0.02 NO_GROUP {Day:5 Hour:5}) might have a corrupted undoMove (Undo(70 AIF2 Mareczek peme LS103 EM7/EM8 {Day:1 Hour:3} <-> 136 AIF2 Koller phys A0.02 NO_GROUP {Day:5 Hour:5})).
>     3) Check your custom VariableListeners (if you have any) for shadow variables that are used by the score constraints with a different score weight between the beforeMoveScore (0hard/-20soft) and the undoScore (0hard/-10soft).

This is the rule that is causing the issue. Because onlyLesson can only be 0 or 1 by my Implementation this either adds -10 or 0 to the scoreDirector.

```
rule "avoidDaysWithOneLesson"
    when
        $lesson : Lesson($only : onlyLesson)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$lesson.getOnlyLesson() * 10);
end
```

And these are the Shadowvariables used. Originally there were only two, the sameDay and previousPeriod.
I just tried to fiddle around if it would be resolved if I just update an Integer (onlyLesson). But that didnt resolve the issue.

```
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = DayLessonVariableListener.class,
        sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "period")})
public List<Lesson> getSameDay() {
    return this.sameDay;
}

@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerRef = @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "sameDay"))
public Period getPreviousPeriod() {
    return previousPeriod;
}

public void setPreviousPeriod(Period period) {
    this.previousPeriod = period;
}

public void addSameDay(Lesson lesson) {
    if (this.getCourse().getSemester().getShortName().equals(lesson.getCourse().getSemester().getShortName())) {
        this.sameDay.add(lesson);
    }
}

public void setSameDay(List<Lesson> sameDay) {
    this.sameDay = sameDay;
}

@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerRef = @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "sameDay"))
public Integer getOnlyLesson() {
    return onlyLesson;
}
```

My question is, is it allowed to call constraints with shadowVariables as the reason, or does this lead to consistency issues between the moves and the scoreDirector?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same when running with FULL_ASSERT?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet yes this is running in FULL_ASSERT, i just updated the post, after apparently fixing my initial Problem. I would be glad if you could have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what i wanted to do is call a softConstraint based on the shadow
>   variables. Is this not allowed?

Soft (and hard) constraints can use shadow variables (that's the point of shadow variables).

> Is this some sort of concurrency issue?

This all happens in the solver thread (or a part thread in Partitioned Search, or a move thread in multithreaded solving). In any case, within one ScoreDirector, it's single threaded, so you don't have to worry about concurrency issues.

Comment: Good, atleast i am using them for what they are supposed to be used, i was worried i missed something. I am really stuck though. The point is, I have that Soft Constraint, that just finds out if the List of other Lessons on that day is empty.
And for some reason the SwapMove's undoMove is corrupted by that rule.
I tried implementing a own SwapMove, but that just does the same thing as the default SwapMove.